# problem with code not being able to go to else block

Tags: python

I just want to be able to move onto the else block if the length of the list is greater than 1 person as of course, what I say to if only one person is coming will not be appropriate to say if 2 or more are coming

```
guests = []
guests_potential = []

attendence_question = input("Are you going to be coming to my house?\n")

while attendence_question == 'yes':
        name = input("Ok! Can I please have your name?\n" )
        guests.append(name)
        #guests_integer = " ".join(guests)
        if len(guests) >= 1: 
            print("Great! So far it is only you that is coming")
            print("----------------")
            attendence_question = input("Hi!\nHow about you?\nAre you going to be coming to my house?\n")
            guests.append(name)
            
        else:
            if len(guests) < 1:
                for number, guest in enumerate(guests, 1):
                    print(number, guest)

guests_potential.append(name)
print("Ok! I've added your name list to the potential attendees!")
```

Comment: After you call `guests.append(name)` it's length will always be greater than or equal to one, why would you expect it to ever hit the else branch? Also the `if len(guests) < 1` will cause it to only try to print when the list is empty even if it did get there.

Comment: Ignoring your if/else logic, your code will add each name entered at the top of your `while` loop to the `guests` list multiple times.  I'm guessing that this isn't what you want.  Also, if the answer to the initial question is not `"yes"`, the line `guests_potential.append(name)` will throw an exception, as the variable `name` will in that case have never been assigned a value.  This question is generally confusing and full of logical errors.  StackOverflow isn't meant to be a place where you dump code and ask others to try to guess what you're trying to do and fix the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement is always being called because it is checking if there is at least 1 name in the guest list. This is always the case because on the previous line you add a name to the guest list.

Instead, just check if there is  1 guest, otherwise do the else loop:

```
while attendence_question == 'yes':
   name = input("Ok! Can I please have your name?\n" )
   guests.append(name)

   if len(guests) == 1: 
       print("Great! So far it is only you that is coming")
       print("----------------")            
   else:
       print("The current guest list is:")
       for number, guest in enumerate(guests):
           print(number, guest)
   
   attendence_question = input("Hi!\nHow about you?\nAre you going to be coming to my house?\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your else block will never do anything visible, because it contains an `if` statement to check that there's less than one guest (so, zero) and then loops over those zero guests